# Infinitesimal generator of Brownian motion on the unit sphere

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

The infinitesimal generator of a standard Brownian motion (as Markovian process) in $\mathbb R$ can be computed with

$$Af(x) := \lim_{t \downarrow 0} \frac{\mathbb{E}^x(f(X_t))-f(x)}{t} = \lim_{t \downarrow 0} \frac{P_tf(x)-f(x)}{t}$$
as $\frac{1}{2} \Delta$.

**How can i use this formula** to compute the generator on the unit sphere?
In the literature (e.g. Oksendal), he uses some "random time change" and other authors used other approaches, but no one uses this formula. I would appreciate a mathematical explanation if(why) the formula cannot be used.

Is it true to say that Brownian motion on the sphere is not Markovian, because state of the process on the sphere is determined not only by its current position but also by how it got to that position?

Comment: Hi Kevin, one thing to keep in mind whenever talking about the generator of a stochastic process is that it is a pair, given by an operator and a domain consisting of functions to which the operator can be applied. Changing the domain of the operator changes which process it describes. This issue is often glossed over in introductory treatments of generators. A basic answer to your question is that the formula you have seen in the past is derived for functions in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and functions on the sphere are defined on a different space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Examples 3.3.2./3.3.3. in ["Stochastic Analysis On Manifolds"](https://sayanmuk.github.io/StochasticAnalysisManifolds.pdf) by Elton P. Hsu. He derives the generator for Brownian motion on the sphere

$$\mathcal{L}f(x):=\frac{1}{2}\Delta_{S}f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\Delta(f(\frac{x}{|x|})),$$

where $\Delta_{S}$ is the [spherical Laplacian.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator#Spherical_Laplacian)

The formula you mentioned does have analogues on manifolds. For example, see theorem 4.9 in ["Heat Kernel and Analysis on Manifolds"](https://bookstore.ams.org/amsip-47) Book by A Grigoryan, where he describes the relation of the semigroup and generator and in particular derives the relation

$$\frac{d}{dt}P_{t}(f)=-\mathcal{L}P_{t}(f),$$

which is the one you mentioned at $t\to 0$ (also see exercises 4.41-42).

But to be clear even in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, one again needs to start from some generator and then define the corresponding semigroup (satisfying the Cauchy-problem) and stochastic process.

Once some basic processes were built, then this procedure was back-engineered too eg. see [Feynman-Kac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula), of the correspondence, so one can start from an SDE and figure out the corresponding generator.

Comment: Thank you. But as i wrote above, do you know why no authors use the formula to compute the generator on the sphere?

Comment: @Kevin I updated

Comment: Thank you for the update. But why no one mentions that they start from the generator? In almost all textbooks, first they have the Brownian motion in $\mathbb R$ and then they compute the generator afterwards.

Comment: Well even then the transition density is picked so that it satisfies the heat equation.